# Hedging against exchange risk

Tags: hedge

How does one hedge against any exchange risk?

---

A Japanese exporter has a €1,000,000 receivable due in one year. Detail a strategy using a money market hdege that will eliminate any exchange rate risk.

1-year rates of interest:

$$
\begin{array}{r|c|c}
\text{Currency} & \text{Borrowing} & \text{Lending}\\
\hline
Dollar\ (\$) & 4.50\ \% & 4.00\ \%  \\
Euro\ (€) & 6.00\ \% & 5.35\ \%  \\
Yen\ (¥) & 1.00\ \% & 0.75\ \%
\end{array}
$$
The spot rates are as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\ Current\ Spot\ Exchange\ Rates & \ & \ One\ Year\ Forward\ Rates\\
\
\$ 1.25 = €1.00 & \ & \$ 1.2262 = €1.00  \\
\$ 1.00 = ¥1.00 & \ & \$ 1.03 = ¥100  \\\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much calculations, this is the approach:

In 1 year you need €1,000,000, how much do you need currently (*$x$*)?

If the euro interest rate is at 6%,

$$ x\ \times\ (1+6\%) = x(1.06) = €\ 1,000,000$$
$$ \begin{align}x\ = \frac{€\ 1,000,000}{1.06} 
\newline \therefore\ x\ = €\ 943,396.22\end{align}$$

With the current spot rate, we can convert € 943,396.22 into dollars by:

$$€\ 943,396.22 \times  \frac{$1.25}{€} = $\ 1,179,245.28$$

You would convert these dollars to yen:

$$\$\ 1,179,245.28 \times \frac{¥\ 100}{$} = ¥\ 117,924,528.30$$

---

*The answer is:*

You would borrow € 943,396.22 today. Convert the euro to dollars at the spot exchange rate, convert these dollars to yen at the spot rate, and receive ¥117,924,528.30

Comment: Using [this](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p35bo15/79-today-Convert-the-euro-to-dollars-at-the-spot-exchange-rate-receive/) as a reference.